# Google Static Maps - Adding custom labels

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a Static Google Map (without the use of any JavaScript) with some markers. I would like to add some descriptions to the markers but since the label is only 1 character long, I don't know how to do it. Any idea?